# show data to modals get error message in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

i want show data to modals but i got the error message, and i already do many ways still stuck pls help

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object

here my code

this my Controller:

```
public function lihatdetail()
{
$this->load->model('Produk_m' , 'produk_m');
if(!empty($this->input->post('ids'))){
    $data['detail'] = $this->produk_m->lihat_detail($this->input->post('ids'));
    foreach ($data as $item) {
        echo 'Nama Barang :'.$item[0]->nama_barang.'<br>';

    }
}else{
    echo 'ID Tidak diketahui';
}
}
```

this My Models:

```
public function lihat_detail($id){
    $this->db->select('b.id_barang');
    $this->db->select('b.nama_barang');
    $this->db->select('b.deskripsi_barang');
    $this->db->select('b.stok_barang');
    $this->db->select('b.size_barang');
    $this->db->select('b.berat_barang');
    $this->db->select('b.foto_barang');
    $this->db->select('k.nama_kategori');
    $this->db->select('b.harga_barang');
    $this->db->select('b.status_barang');
    $this->db->from('nm_barang b');
    $this->db->join('nm_kategori_barang k', 'k.id_kategori = b.id_kategori');
    $this->db->where('b.id_barang', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get()->row_array();
}
```

and My Ajax:

```
$(document).on("click", ".kirimdata", function () {
    var id_barang=$(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:'<?php echo base_url().'Produk/lihatdetail'?>',
            data:{ ids: id_barang },
            success:function(response){
              $(".hasil-data").html(response);
            }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code section

```
$data['detail'] = $this->produk_m->lihat_detail($this->input->post('ids'));
foreach ($data as $item) {
  echo 'Nama Barang :'.$item[0]->nama_barang.'<br>';
}
```

You want to actually see what you are getting using var_dump() , or print_r() if you want. Try...

```
$data['detail'] = $this->produk_m->lihat_detail($this->input->post('ids'));
foreach ($data as $item) {
  var_dump(); // Inspect the array elements
  //echo 'Nama Barang :'.$item[0]->nama_barang.'<br>';
}
```

I am guessing that you need to either **change $data['detail'] to simply $detail** OR in the foreach loop **change $data to $data['detail']**

What you see in the var_dump() output will reveal all...

Comment: i change this code to var_dump($data) and the modals show message just 'NULL' , Is there any wrong code in my models or ajax?

Comment: oke fixed by return the $query and change to $item['nama_barang'] . thanks for helping me hehehe -A-

Comment: I am glad you got it sorted out. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

if u still want to use

```
  $item[0]->nama_barang
```

change your query by remove (*_array())

```
  $query = $this->db->get()->row;
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but i already fix that but this suggestion is ok :)